# Second website on subdirectory gives 404 errors

Tags: web, magento-1.7

i really hope someone can help me here, i’ve been fighting 2 days to solve this problem. 
I have created a second website using a subdirectory “/micro_auricolare” with new .htaccess and index.php

This is the URL:

http://www.eartecs.com/micro_auricolare/

it is displayed correctly, but every link from there gives 404 error:
login, customer account, cart...
these are the changes i have made to index.php in the subdirectory folder:

```
compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . ‘../includes/config.php’; 
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) { 
include $compilerConfig; 
} 

$mageFilename = ‘../app/Mage.php’; 
$maintenanceFile = ‘maintenance.flag’;
```

and at the end of the file:

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER[’MAGE_RUN_CODE’]) ? $_SERVER[’MAGE_RUN_CODE’] : ‘’; 

/* Run store or run website */ 
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER[’MAGE_RUN_TYPE’]) ? $_SERVER[’MAGE_RUN_TYPE’] :        ‘website’; 

Mage::run(’micro_auricolare’, ‘website’);
```

i have created the website in the backend and changed secure and usecure base URL.
i have done this before on magento 1.5, but now, on 1.7. i'm completely stuck.

thanks for your precious help

Comment: Have you tried RewriteBase /your sub directory name/ with .htaccess, it may be fix your issue.

Comment: yes, i did, but today my hosting said they don't use Apache so .htaccess is not read.